# PHP multidimensional array key value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am working with multidimensional arrays;
I use the arsort function to get the array that has been added the latest. This all works fine

```
arsort($this->shoppingBag);
$this->productToShow = key($this->shoppingBag);
```

When i want to use this array i do:

```
$prodName = key($this->shoppingBag[$this->productToShow]);
```

this gives me the correct product with the correct name that I need. When i do

```
$count = $this->shoppingBag[$this->productToShow[$prodName]];
```

It gives me an "Undefined index" error.

When I echo the array with the key as a string i get the correct value from that array..

Why is this and how can I get the value with that key?

edit:

```
array(4) 
{
    [38] => array(1) 
    {
        ["SAMSUNG LE32D450"] => int(3)
    }
    [32] => array(1) 
    {
        ["Inspiron 15R"] => int(1)
    }
    [29] => array(1) 
    {
        ["XPS 15"] => int(25)
    }
    [37] => array(1) 
    {
        ["Logitech M185 Black"] => int(10)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include a sample of the multi-dimensional array data?

Comment: Check my most recent edit. I am pretty sure that should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this as simple as `$this->productToShow` is just a key variable and not an array. So the call to an index of that variable is undefined. Then wouldn't the answer you are looking for be `$count = $this->shoppingBag[$this->productToShow][$prodName];`.

Comment: $this->productToShow = key($this->shoppingBag);

Comment: that worked. thanks
seems to be as simple indeed, I think i'm doing way to much time working with those arrays today. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$count = $this->shoppingBag[$this->productToShow];
```

Comment: Is the count one of the variables in the array? Or is the count the number of elements in the array?

Answer (score 0):

`$this->productToShow` is not an array. So seeing as `$prodName` is the key of a particular item in `$this->shoppingBag`,

I am assuming that you want $count to return the last key Because if we omitted the incorrectly applied `[$prodName]` to the `$this->productToShow` key, $count will return the value of the last key in the shopping bag.